# google adsense in facebook application

Tags: facebook, adsense

how can i add google adsense in facebook application

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the code in a seperate html file and load that file into a frame and call that using the fb:iframe code.

There are issues with Googles TOS in doing this but this is explained and code examples are given here: http://netodex.com/?p=223

Andy

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you can't have any more ads on facebook by google adsense. since google did not sign a compliance agreement with facebook.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
google_ad_client = "pub-0663894775040736";
/* 300x250, date de création 06/05/11 */
google_ad_slot = "0095835646";
google_ad_width = 300;
google_ad_height = 250;
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: While *technically* possible, using this at face value would likely violate Google Adsense's and/or Facebook's Terms of Use.